# Probability Density Function of the sum of N random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

I have N random variables: $X_{1}, X_{2}, ... X_{n}$ which are all independent.

The probability density function for the ith random variable is $f_{i}(x)$.

What is the pdf $f_{X}(x)$ where $f_{X}(x)$ is the sum of all the random variables?

This is similar to calculating the sum of n dice, but a little more complicated.

Does anyone have any suggestions, tips, or places for me to look to help guide me to the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the random variables are i.i.d, why do you need to distinguish between the marginal densities of the random variables? That is, aren't $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$ the _same_ function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$?

Comment: Good eye. They're only independent not identical.  I've made the correction to the question

Comment: Answers to this question appear in several thousand posts on this site.  You can find some of them with [a search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdf+random+variable+sum). Although few explicitly address the problem of summing more than two random variables, that doesn't matter: you sum the first two, then sum that with the third, and keep on going in that manner.  A [search for "sum random variable distribution"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+random+variable+distribution) looks like it's turning up many worked examples.